# Place custom icon inside bootstrap button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a custom icon inside of a bootstrap button, this is the html part:

```
<button class="btn btn-info pull-right toggle" data-pausetext="Break In" 
 data-resumetext="Resume" ><i class="icon-play"></i> Clock In</button>
```

and on the stylesheet have this:

```
.icon-play {
background-image : url(../img/Clock-Play.png) no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}
```

but the icon is not showing inside the button...please help...thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all your `<i>` element doesn't have a height and width property.
But adding height and width alone wouldn't do what you want because `<i>` is an inline element so you want to add another property as well i-e. `display: inline-block` 
Then the last thing to make it perfect would be to add `background-size: cover` (to adjust icon exactly into its container element)

```
.icon-play{
  background-image : url(../img/Clock-Play.png);
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your icon element doesn't have a width or height - try adding a padding on there.

Also, you might want to look into `cover` instead of `no-repeat` - it will automatically stretch the background (proportionately) to cover the entire element, so it will fit whatever element you throw it in.